# Timer, SetInterval, Alarm, etc

Tags: actionscript-3, timer, arguments, setinterval, alarm

Help turning multiple functions into a a few functions.

```
var myNumberOne = 10;
var myNumberTwo = 100;
```

function one would create a timer or interval that fire 2 times every second, Traceing the word "food", It would when finished, "myNumberOne += 10" making myNumberOne = 20;

function two would create a timer or interval that fire 5 times every half-second, Traceing the word "ben", It would when finished, "myNumberTwo += 50" making myNumberTwo = 250;

For two functions this is fine, but if I have 100s of possible combinations, I cannot think on this should be done, without intervals , timers, functions etc... interfering with each-other, and passing arguments through time.

Thanks for any help.

for clarification: I waant to call a function like this

```
setTimeFunction("myTimeOne", myNumberOne, 2,1000,10, "ben");
setTimeFunction("myTimeTwo", myNumberTwo, 5,500,50,"food");
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, first, you need to compose a generic method that would perform a number of similar actions. Tracing is easy, but you cannot pass a variable to change directly because you'll pass a value, not a reference to variable. In order to do as you want you need to pass it as a pair "container object" and "variable name" to use the square bracket notation.

```
function myownDothings(target:Object, varname:String, adiff:int, totrace:String):void
{
    // Use square bracket notation to change the targeted variable.
    target[varname] += adiff;

    // Trace the given argument.
    trace(totrace);
}
```

Ok, now the <strike>simple</strike> complicated part. There's a **setTimeout(...)** [function](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#setTimeout()) that calls the given method many times with a given timeout, but it's official documentation officially advises the use of **Timer** [class](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html).

I hope you know how to [work with classes](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/as3-101-oop-introduction-basix--active-5789), because the thing you want calls for OOP and fitting it into the frame scripts will result in something ugly. So, you need to compose a class that remembers function to call, timeout settings and a bunch of arguments as well.

```
package
{
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;

    public class Ticker
    {
        // You need to keep the references to the things you use,
        // or else Garbage Collector might think you don't need it.
        static private var list:Array = new Array;

        // Instead of static method you can use the "constructor" way,
        // but I find it more stylish and it's one more thing for
        // you to google and learn of, which I totally approve.
        // The ... construction allows to pass a random number
        // of arguments (after fixed arguments) as an Array.
        static public function create(handler:Function, timeout:int, ...args:Array):void
        {
            var aTicker:Ticker;

            // Brackets () are not mandatory with the "new" operator
            // if there are no mandatory constructor arguments.
            aTicker = new Ticker;

            // Store all the necessary data in the new instance. That's the 
            // point of OOP scripting here: you want to make 100 different 
            // tickers and you need each of them to keep some custom data.
            aTicker.timeout = timeout;
            aTicker.handler = handler;
            aTicker.args = args;

            // Finally, run the ticker.
            aTicker.start();

            // Store the created instance into the keeper list
            // to prevent Garbage Collector from destroying it.
            list.push(aTicker);
        }

        // Again, fear the Garbage Collector.
        private var clock:Timer;

        // Keep in mind that timeout is not exactly accurate
        // as it aligns to the SWF's frame rate. Setting it up to call
        // more times a second than FPS will pose to be a meaningless act.
        private var timeout:int;

        // The reference to the method to call.
        private var handler:Function;

        // The list of arguments to pass to the method above.
        private var args:Array;

        // This method is called from the "create" method
        // to finalize things and start ticking.
        private function start():void
        {
            // Create a Timer instance with a given timeout.
            clock = new Timer(timeout);

            // Subscribe the listener to the Timer.
            clock.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick);

            // Start the Timer.
            clock.start();
       }

        // The Timer instance will trigger this method
        // (approximately) every given timeout of milliseconds.
        private function onTick(e:TimerEvent):void
        {
            // Now the idea is to call the given method
            // passing the list of given arguments to it.
            // Normally you don't need to pass the "this" object
            // to a method unless you use unnamed unbound closures.
            // (which I personally consider a heresy and don't recommend to use)
            // So you just pass "null" as the first argument and everything is fine.
            handler.apply(null, args);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the usage. It's where all the horrors above finally shine.

```
import Ticker;

var myNumberOne = 10;
var myNumberTwo = 100;

// Fire 2 times every second, increase "myNumberOne" by 10, trace the word "ben".
// So, 2 times a second it will call: myownDothings(this, "myNumberOne", 10, "ben");
Ticker.create(myownDothings, 1000 / 2, this, "myNumberOne", 10, "ben");

// Fire 5 times every half a second, increase "myNumberTwo" by 50, trace the word "food".
// So, 10 times a second it will call: myownDothings(this, "myNumberTwo", 50, "food");
Ticker.create(myownDothings, 500 / 5, this, "myNumberTwo", 50, "food");
```

Comment: Thank you! I have yet to implement (or try to...) this solution yet, but it looks both practical, economical, and educational for me. I am familiar with classes, and OOP a little, but this gives me a good place to dive into this type of thing. Thanks again, and for the comments in the code. Very verbose.